# Cannot create a new environment or install libraries in Ananconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to create a new environment from Anaconda navigator and from conda prompt. I cannot install python libraries as well. I get below error:

> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2
> Elapsed: -
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
> HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
> If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
> a support request with your network engineering team.
> SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([(\'SSL routines\', \'tls_process_server_certificate\', \'certificate verify failed\')])")))'))

I tried the solutions from the web, still no help

Answer (score 2):

Try using a terminal and use the following command.

`conda create -n testenv python=3.5`

Let me know if you have any questions! The video below might help

https://youtu.be/pNqXHQUSEsc

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24976067)

Comment: It's a YouTube link tho

Comment: Hi @baller97, the edit you made to your answer is exactly what we're looking for. Links to third-party sites, no matter how (currently) popular the site is, are great for reference, but we want to have an actual answer here and not force a user to visit another site, which might be dead (videos do get taken down from time to time) or blocked in certain regions. So thanks for your edit!